# Linking multiple c files with a header file

Tags: c, makefile, linker

I'm new to linking c files together and was wondering if somebody could help me link 2 c files with a header file. In my make file I have:

```
all: runMe

runMe: a2.o functions.o

    gcc a2.o functions.o -o runMe

a2.o: a2.c structs.h
    gcc -Wall -pedantic -std=c99 -c a2.c

functions.o: functions.c structs.h
    gcc -Wall -pedantic -std=c99 -c functions.c
```

Where structs.h has the structs I used as well as functions prototypes that are used in functions.c. Do I put #include "structs.h" in both c files, or just one of them? If it's not in both I get undeclared identifies, unknown types, etc. If I include it in both I get errors like:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_acs_map", referenced from:
  _main in a2.o
  _forward in functions.o
  _backwards in functions.o
"_endwin", referenced from:
  _main in a2.o
"_init_pair", referenced from:
  _forward in functions.o
  _backwards in functions.o
"_initscr", referenced from:
  _main in a2.o
"_printw", referenced from:
  _main in a2.o
"_start_color", referenced from:
  _main in a2.o
"_stdscr", referenced from:
  _main in a2.o
  _forward in functions.o
  _backwards in functions.o
  _restartScreen in functions.o
  _cleanScreen in functions.o
"_waddch", referenced from:
  _main in a2.o
  _forward in functions.o
  _backwards in functions.o
"_wattr_off", referenced from:
  _forward in functions.o
  _backwards in functions.o
"_wattr_on", referenced from:
  _forward in functions.o
  _backwards in functions.o
"_wclear", referenced from:
  _restartScreen in functions.o
  _cleanScreen in functions.o
"_wgetch", referenced from:
  _main in a2.o
"_wgetnstr", referenced from:
  _main in a2.o
"_wmove", referenced from:
  _main in a2.o
  _forward in functions.o
  _backwards in functions.o
"_wrefresh", referenced from:
  _main in a2.o
```

Comment: You'll need to post your source code...

Comment: The correct way to do this is to include it in both files, but for best practice you'd use a `#ifdef` include guard. Meanwhile, the other errors are unrelated; they come from the linker.

Comment: I added the source code, there were more functions then I put up there, but that is basically what is in my functions.c file

Comment: Functions like `initscr()` suggest you need to add `-lncurses` to the end of the linking line.  Do not put the library before the object files; it should go after them.  A few platforms work OK when the libraries precede the object files, but most don't, and you should plan for porting to other platforms.

Answer (score 1):

Your header is fine, you can include it in both C files.

The errors are coming from the linker.
It is not able to find the ncurses library functions (initscr, startcolor etc.) that you are using in your code.

You need to first find if ncurses library is installed in your system, if yes, specify the path to where the libncurses library is available as below.

```
runMe: a2.o functions.o
    gcc -LPATH_TO_NCURSES_LIB a2.o functions.o -lncurses -o runMe
```

What OS are you on? Windows, Linux, BSD?

Comment: Im on mac OS, I should have it installed (hopefully? Sorry im new to this)

Comment: Most likely you do have it installed otherwise the compiler would have complained about not being able to find #include <ncurses.h>

Now you just need to find where the libraries are - check under /usr/lib/ if you have anything with libncurses*

Or just add -lncurses to your runMe target and see if the errors go away.

Comment: That seems to fix it, but when I actually run the code I get seg faults

Comment: EDIT: Nevermind, thanks for all the help! The segfault was coming from the filewriting. I took out the folders so thats why I was getting that. Everything compiles fine now

Comment: put the library path and then the library name AFTER the object file names.  this is because parameters to gcc are operated on in the order listed,  and when the lib info is first, there are no unresolved references, so nothing is extracted from the library. (the unresolved references are not generated until the *.o files are processed